# Turn off google photos backup programmatically in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to turn off google photos backup in Android in a programmatic manner using my own android app?

Answer (score 1):

Very unlikely! The photos app would need to have a mechanism to listen to these events and could introduce security risk for the user.. E.g Why would you want to turn off somebody's google photo sync? How would the user know that you turned it off on their behalf?